# Access DoubleBuffer from native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a direct ByteBuffer that should hold 15 double values created the following way

```
DoubleBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(15*8).asDoubleBuffer();
```

I wanna access this buffer from native code and for the sake of simplicity just write the number from 1.0 to 15.0 in it. From the java side the method is

```
native public static void write(DoubleBuffer buff, int len);
```

and my C++ code is then

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ByteBufferTest_write(JNIEnv *env, jclass cl, jobject buff, jint len)
{
    double* arr = (double*) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buff);
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        arr[i] = (double) i;
    }
}
```

Calling the following in java

```
write(buff, 15);

for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
    System.out.println(buff.get(i));
}
```

just prints garbage.

The question is, do I correctly allocate the DoubleBuffer? Would it be better to write

```
DoubleBuffer s = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(15 * Double.SIZE/8).asDoubleBuffer();
```

or is there even a beter way?

The second question is, why is this not working? Is the cast to `double*` in the JNI code wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Java's XxxxBuffer is big endian.  If you are using one of the Intel/AMD or some ARM processors it will be little endian by default.

Try using

```
DoubleBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(15*8)
                              .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asDoubleBuffer();
```

BTW: Using nativeOrder() is usually faster as well. ;)